# why the output always "System.Object"

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

in EF I want tto get the first value of query so I use

```
ExecuteStoreQuery<object>(Query, null).FirstOrDefault();
```

because I don't know what's the actual returned data type 
if the value comming is numeric is crash , so I used the following

```
ExecuteStoreQuery<object>(Query, null).Select(x => x.ToString()).FirstOrDefault()
```

but the resulted string  always `System.Object`

any idea how to get the actual value

Best regards

Comment: The resulting string is always System.Object, sounds like you are displaying the result incorrectly.

Comment: I don't know.. how are you displaying the result?